# Issue with 'avenc_aac' encoder while combining video && audio streams

Tags: macos, gstreamer

I want to combine audio and video streams and save the resulting stream into a file. Following below is shown a command line I try to use.

> gst-launch-1.0 avfvideosrc -e device-index=0 !
>   video/x-raw,width=720,height=576 ! tee name=t t. ! queue !
>   osxvideosink sync=false t. ! videoconvert ! vtenc_h264_hw
>   realtime=true max-keyframe-interval=5 ! queue ! mux. osxaudiosrc
>   device=0 ! audioconvert ! avenc_aac ! queue ! mux. mp4mux name=mux !
>   filesink location='output.mp4'

gst-launch shows an error:

> illegal instruction: 4

The problem here is with  avenc_aac encoder.
What parameters should be added to avenc_aac encoder to get working command line?

May be it is possible to use another one encoder for such purposes?

Comment: add more debugging output by using `GST_DEBUG=avenc_aac:2` or simply  `GST_DEBUG=2`

Comment: thanks for your reply, we received the same output message: illegal instruction: 4

Answer (score 0):

What are your system specs? Perhaps the encoder requires some SSE4/AVX instructions your CPU does not support. An alternative AAC encoder is `voaacenc`.

Comment: We tried voaacenc  - the same issue. We use Mac mini (mid 2011)

Comment: Maybe it is something in your base GStreamer installation. Maybe you need to build it yourself for you exact instruction set for that (kinda old) machine.